# Get base class for a type in class hierarchy

Tags: c++, c++11

Is is possible to get base class type in a class hierarchy?

For example:

```
struct A{};
struct B{} : public A;
struct C{} : public B;
```

I want some template that will have `typedef Base<T>::Type` inside like this:

```
Base<A>::Type == A
Base<B>::Type == A
Base<C>::Type == A
```

Is this possible? What about the case when I have multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) can help you

```
#include <type_traits>

std::is_base_of<B, D>()
```

> If D is derived from B or if both are the same non-union class,
>   provides the member constant value equal to true. Otherwise value is
>   false.

You can use it to check if a class is base class of another or not :

```
std::is_base_of<A, A>()   // Base<A>::Type == A

std::is_base_of<A, B>()   // Base<B>::Type == A

std::is_base_of<A, C>()   // Base<C>::Type == A
```

Answer (score 30):

Classes in C++ can have more than one base class, so there's no sense in having a "get me *the* base" trait.

However, the TR2 additions include new compiler-supported traits `std::tr2::bases` and `std::tr2::direct_bases`, which returns an opaque type list of base classes.

I'm not sure whether this will make it into C++14, or whether it'll be released independently, but GCC already [seems to support this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01610_source.html).

Comment: That's a kind of a type trait that can't be implemented without compiler magic, is it?

Comment: This is more appropriate for my question, but I accepted the other answer because in combination with std::conditional it solves my problem.

Comment: @jrok: well, obviously not, how would the trait learn about the types in the program ? On the other hand, this is the kind of little things that get us closer to a full compile-time reflection system.

Comment: @Felics how can this not be the accepted answer? you question was not whether `B` is indeed a base of `D` (mapping to bool), but which `B` is `D` derived from (one-to-many mapping).

Comment: @rhalbersma I explained in a previous comment

Comment: @Felics as an aside, in the future both describe your *real* problem and the problem you are having with your attempted solution.  While stack overflow is decent at reading minds, it works even better if it doesn't have to!

Comment: if compiler magic needed anyway why wrap it into STL? It should be direct keyword `base` accessible within classes.

Comment: @Sergei: Sorry, I don't follow -- how is a "direct keyword" anything other than compiler magic?

Comment: @KerrekSB, no-one said that it other, the question, why STL affected

Answer (score 8):

This might be a nice way to do it, depending on your use case.  Declare a typedef of the base class named `base` in the base class itself.

Then derived classes `X` will inherit it as the typename `X::base`.

So `B::base` is `A`, and `C::base` is `A`.

```
struct A
{
    typedef A base;
};

struct B : A {};
struct C : B {};

template<class X>
void f()
{
    typename X::base x;
}

int main()
{
    f<B>();
    f<C>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With certain limitations, it's possible!

- Each base that needs to be detectable in this manner has to inherit from a certain CRTP base. (Or, possibly, contain some kind of macro.)
- You get a list of all parents, including indirect ones.

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwBspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgABwA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BehlZjgJhEdEscQmJAKy2mPYlDEIETMQEeT5%2BgfWNOS1tBGVRsfFJqQqt7Z0FXLZTQ%2BEjlWO1AJS2qF7EyOwc5gDM4cjeWADUJgduyJPoWFSX2CYaAIKHx6eYF1dOk8SYrEezzeZiODBOXnOlzcBAAnmlMOEsKoga93uDPt83F5HLRCLDUW9XgRMCw0gYSVi4QjmGwzgAVQl/LwOM6tYDAkzJKyvM58s5eLJGNnwr6XAAiDMuPLeyXF0s5xNJ5KYlOh1MYrC%2BADpdcomQRiCyCCKEQB9PGTTnc4H8s7hPERM6TVV4ZBnNAMSaYVRpYjOgjoEAgLIAL0wZpNYbFB0l0dQVF12ogyjWCrRcvTRJetMwCjSTF29rJtGtMrtnu9vv9ADdUHh0GcmOhaGaAGp4TAAdwsTCUEDWFxtcrOAHpR2cXmd0D4WLDJ%2BKQmy2sBMARtYqp/ySSXVTGYaLc2dxaQA0GQ3hw5GzgBJQl25ms3tKDvd%2BK2/lc8t2z%2BgvBUadMBoCJ0AgM0zQAcUiOQ3HAwdzACBCzjAMB7iWUDwJOQxgDgj8fwuUE/SYYAWCYM4ILcNxpzwYiGEyRx3TSQUEDwn9DiIkiyIoqj8Fo%2Bi3XtYA6P%2BRtzDMABaAB1OiGHEncVRJcSqGITsGHQMTWLtQ5XH/TT%2BWU1TG0rElqybHFUCbFt207Hs%2B0wCBn0wV8u3iNMDm/fD3gAtCQLAyDoNgs14MCJCUJ8zAMLNLCjFw3l8IIg4ONI8jKOovjJgEjI0j0vltLU3S4tyzN3M3O15IpfcNSPE8z2DaNrxvU8qq1M4rAOJ5CoDI0nzsySVJJYhWK/HKzgM1wPQEKs/TMohLNbZzHIcuznPfK4arvdr4O5f4CG2Bhlw5K42qeYd5RKzNOq5M6ZVY8q9ypQ8Wpq5q6TkBg8AARy8TBT1uOrLwjE0b2%2BSUNCax66QlM46wbe9%2BUfE0KkchQzhAWqQHCElgGIMQosm1pBGhP6LyvAhTw27AhysYqbs6u61SuF6vmeiGvjez7vt%2BwN/tJ284b5BGziRuyFGhGr2a%2Bn7b1PLATg1CBm3mmzFsclbBrW8mgVOjZofrUC1jcym0eJzHMGx3HjMMAgie5knAdPYWlFFjWzglzm%2BcsOZddh9rgxrMRvseKmrqzW7lQqh6aSe8Go7pY7WMFxyby9eIBtR1rev61a3Bqx28zF09jr9gOpeO4OadK7dw/u9VWaldrWOMn1pphxtFbNAAlM28G9YhkYgVuzgAKi26nJXHSdp1necXkXZdiFXddK75enKrrxkG86wWu%2BAHuBuR9PZdoeX253vf4mR6EN%2BwKB6WHtYGC8WhaDSQ0dfZaFW8eAc00u07Q7ptXBmB5Y5fHpDHTUdIKYJ0NMaDOSgwiTBCKgLs5drrLzZEAteoCGRc3PPVE0SZoFb1gT1BBe9kFdivng4MSIfRmiUJLcEmBoQ3iTECTeW4ioeR/C6BiE0vQmWmhqC0e9oRHxPlZBadklovhstncBfMG7azWOw9qZwEANARMQAcaCRqCnCMAU0MZJQSNFBATRL94g/yzFpCuaJAG7mAUzeuHUuFdTgY5RBJo0ZeIoSg6h6NSIAGsIx0NUAwzATDdjQggHgEswYz690vlca%2Bw05QOx8Cktwiiv6%2BxAP7bwmBDZB3SegjM8oHEvFXpHSBYDCQGOFDEOyojJgg2MUeeJ5Jgx%2BKtKkx4wYNQAOqVg2pR40mvETnZMsYcnH7hGi4k8I1iaahiPQM0/5Iw23PD3M0zSlBmgTGaGsgSzrYBoSAR%2Bz9X7EC2eoqGVyX6GlIAsuuXTaA9LssnJQ7Rs41WvsGGS2BVDn0EO0x5NyhqcLtGNNSAipq1j1nNTu3dkkiwHkikeeiKnDOBILKcvjplXDePc/%2BJVJmkJNBYdOjloTHVPFOMpWZBZUUJUoaEbhSlkplILSUbKWFrUeIXU8VEmXkuzDU2uOCJkvEHn6TG9JzG/1lDwryakgJnDNAAWSELBNs2AO4wPPGgHEWJoSarNMoDu2B6T0gAJpmgAGJyEiDkm8AB5SI4EzVXGQvsGobgGBgH2OKrSoIGjspIcarYJpoTmvAs611QgbwQW9XG31waTABqDSG1V4b8oPBxeK4EmMzikXCAOGZJDXTIDNH2H5BAIBnH2RGS01tBX5OjCDKGkgzhuR4fKwQiqETQhba09tOcOE337WOCcGpvHqmItCEl5yDp0qFWuq4nL2pNSXR2p4O6zgkCwP6Ui85/bEAJBUjgGwPkcBqLwPwHAtCkFQJwTllhrDOi2DsMUoIeCkAIJoG9GxgkgAODUbUkgagaGSAcAIiQzDJAQ7Bsw%2BhOCSEfcB19nBeAKBAGDIDz6b2kDgLAGAiAUCoDJHQeI5BKBoBo/QBIwAuBcDQzQY%2B8R8MQBiNhmI4Q2iwk4ABxjbBBDuoYLQYTxHSBYFIkYcQsn8D/AcHgGseZsM%2BkwMgHEewX2mzvS%2BvEMQcaXo8FgETvBDTxKsxsKgBhgAKGcu6mkVmZCCBEGIdgUgPPyCUGobDug5gGCMCgaw1h9B4BiPhyAGxUCvxyPhjg4lbgSlMJ%2BywZgNBnCkmIWguXJI%2BkNGRcSCJ0BWzdOJeIxASAo3Eu6g4eGGg6aaC4NSMw/BzFCEsCoVRCiZGyAITrA3ig5GGH1sYcw7Ctf6AsEb02WtqYEAMdoE3RgJGm/NzwXQ9AujW71jbEgNgKB/bsPQhpMB7B4LezgD7SBPpfW%2BjgqhEgBHEgEXtwBkDujY9qLgZwIAfqsJYU8uBCAkASl7DwTH4hQ7WNZ4DBtSBgYg9qA4Bw2M1BqAATmSGYJDiQuA1GkHezDpAWAgBgw97Dz28MEcA0j0jFGLEgBjUxMmFAICMbSLRzbwR8BEH5/wTzohxC%2BZF/5lQ6hZNdhxmkOz6H71Ydk8991OIOdHoAq997n2zjfd%2B1wbUZhAcw958x%2BHiPiPI80c2MYA4lfk8p9Tx7vA6e2AZ0RrQyOwNmCN7jmoiRJC1BxwTxDtQldNZp6r3DjPrfM/gGRyjPO%2Bf0e59R83YxoqsYOBoOYnGBo8b47JgTzBL3ubE4wAgknpPYfk9hJTL6VOzY08ll92ndMkmw4Z7DJmzOwgs9d6zKlKfcBIw54izmbKucYO5yXXnxfSEl4oaXQX/D6GwuFzLNgTOxYdwlpoyXUuBnSxFrLOW8vP0K8VnGuXyuVeQNV4gtXiD1ca81vozgICuAW8ENS62Vh%2BcightcgdtZh0hBsmgAD%2BtFtP9mhtt8gutehZsVsFhoCpt5hBhf99tFhygjsuATszsfNAN/gh9btldo8ntOAdcPte1s8zh2NtQNAmDTcz8bAzhwchcocRUM8%2BcEozAEc49vcNhbcT1KBQNwMDhjdYNJBg9khahkh8d5DHdeBncwZXccMOB6dCMmck9Wd2ccQ08U9mN18IoIdhdZAF8fMl9ZAV9AtZd5dFc717sNC1cNdTUEwzgaC9d6CuApDmCAcgdeCLdDgBCrdhDSBRD7dyCncqd1DadY98MdDrcJC/dtRQ8IMccuANBJANBQREgsjSdOAo9XDY8vcSM9CWckBjC6MucaiEgaxkA0g0hjkuAccLQ9xJgzRVBPs%2BA6BC9KBi8X1S8hMK9qNxNq8pMZMm9SQG99NeBm81NW8tNVAdM9Nu9BAGhe9ot%2B9B93MbNR8bs%2BBHMp9uwZ8n0AN58xdrC/M7CZcX1dADgN8wsMsQcd9os994tEtJpOBRw/pXjrAKpJgP8UC/Bv8OswCkCes8DADRsQDf9gCoDDtYTYDQTVsOhIS9slsmh0T0D%2BccDsC0DkSYDCDthzs5hLsyClcXCEiXs9cWAFBGjoY2jtQgSTQgc2CwdBdIdDhodgi4dDgDhBDyibcAQxCHdfczAmDkhJApAagpA8dkhYMccVCKc4jKC3dEjPddCqi2d3DOcGN%2BSEgnizChc9ArjvMJAbDBA7jsM5cmAFcx9yCaSY8OB1cCBNdPCeje0GSmSawWS2TTcjSEohTwiQNIixTojVS1CNTNDtChDwzfcjc8icdEMIMDg8c8cahQRI8VcqCtCEzkc70zA8zNSCyRSNgNNX8cgQBJAgA%3D%3D%3D)</kbd>

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeindex>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct tag
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename ...P>
struct type_list
{
    inline static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(P);
};

namespace impl
{
    constexpr void adl_ViewBase() {} // A dummy ADL target.

    template <typename D, std::size_t I>
    struct BaseViewer
    {
        #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
        #pragma GCC diagnostic push
        #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnon-template-friend"
        #endif
        friend constexpr auto adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer);
        #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
        #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
        #endif
    };

    template <typename D, std::size_t I, typename B>
    struct BaseWriter
    {
        friend constexpr auto adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>) {return tag<B>{};}
    };

    template <typename D, typename Unique, std::size_t I = 0, typename = void>
    struct NumBases : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};

    template <typename D, typename Unique, std::size_t I>
    struct NumBases<D, Unique, I, decltype(adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>{}), void())> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, NumBases<D, Unique, I+1, void>::value> {};

    template <typename D, typename B>
    struct BaseInserter : BaseWriter<D, NumBases<D, B>::value, B> {};

    template <typename T>
    constexpr void adl_RegisterBases(void *) {} // A dummy ADL target.

    template <typename T>
    struct RegisterBases : decltype(adl_RegisterBases<T>((T *)nullptr), tag<void>())
    {};

    template <typename T, typename I>
    struct BaseListLow {};

    template <typename T, std::size_t ...I>
    struct BaseListLow<T, std::index_sequence<I...>>
    {
        static constexpr type_list<decltype(adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<T, I>{}))...> helper() {}
        using type = decltype(helper());
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct BaseList : BaseListLow<T, std::make_index_sequence<(impl::RegisterBases<T>{}, NumBases<T, void>::value)>> {};
}

template <typename T>
using base_list = typename impl::BaseList<T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    template <
        typename D,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, D>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr,
        typename impl::BaseInserter<D, T>::nonExistent = nullptr
    >
    friend constexpr void adl_RegisterBases(void *) {}
};


struct A : Base<A> {};
struct B : Base<B>, A {};
struct C : Base<C> {};
struct D : Base<D>, B, C {};

template <typename T>
void printType()
{
    #ifndef _MSC_VER
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    #else
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << '\n';
    #endif
};

int main()
{
    static_assert( base_list<D>::size == 4 );
    printType<base_list<D>>(); // typeList<tag<A>, tag<B>, tag<C>, tag<D>>, order may vary
}
```

Here's what's going on:

- You use stateful template metaprogramming to create a list of types, which you can append types to by instantiating a specific template.
- Using a CRTP base, you add a `friend` function to each class that needs to be detectable in this manner. Those functions are made uncallable with SFINAE, but merely **considering** them during overload resolution instantiates the template that appends the corresponding base class to the list.
- You invoke this overloaded function with ADL, and since overloads from all bases are considered and are attempted to be instantiated, you get a list of bases.

Answer (score 1):

@HolyBlackCat's answer is brilliant, but opaque. Here's my attempt at explaining it.

Working through the program step by step:

- Our first trick: `friend` functions in classes can be declared *and defined* from within a class. This essentially adds a *non-member* function to the class's scope.

  - Subtrick: If we define our `friend` function in a class *template*, we have access to the specific template parameters used to define that specialization, and we can put those parameters in places the compiler -- and other templates -- can see.

    ```cpp
    constexpr auto adl_ViewBase() {} //Dummy ADL target

    template <typename T>
    struct tag
    {
        using type = T;
    }

    namespace impl {
        template <typename D, typename B>
        struct BaseWriter
        {
            friend constexpr auto adl_ViewBase(D) {return tag<B>{};}
        };
    }
    ```

    Now, by putting an instance of `BaseWriter` into the base of `D` we want to detect, we can make the compiler add a corresponding overload of `adl_ViewBase` to the class scope that encodes the type of the base in the return type of the function.
  - Since it's not actually a member function, we can generically refer to `adl_ViewBase` and force ADL to create a pool of candidates consisting precisely of functions of our choice.
  - If we were to map this template-level meta-level code down to familiar object-level C++, this step would essentially define a class we might call an "unlinked list", to which we can append new elements. We don't have a way of actually accessing it yet, though.
- Second trick: The above code will run into problems if we actually try to build too far on it, due to a subtlety in the way templates on classes and friend functions interact. In order that a specific friend function has access rights to a specific specialization of the class template, every friend function defined within a templated class is by default distinguished despite being implicitly `inline`, so if they have the same name and call signature they will be considered in violation of ODR. We can restore the 'normal' behavior by providing a forward declaration for each specific template-specialized function signature, which is easiest to achieve by providing the declaration in a template with similar template parameters.

  ```cpp
      //...
      template <typename D, std::size_t I>
      struct BaseViewer {
          friend constexpr auto viewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>);
      };

      template <typename D, std::size_t I, typename B>
      struct BaseWriter
      {
          friend constexpr auto viewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>) {return tag<B>{};}
      };
  ```

  - We shouldn't complain, though, because in the process, we'll create a simple way of actually getting at the information we've extracted later. Assuming we can (a) find some way of passing unique values of `I` into the various `BaseWriter`s and (b) keep track of the total number of valid values, we can systematically retrieve all the functions (and thus all the type tags) later by just querying the return types of `viewBase` for every valid `I`.
  - In other words, the "unlinked list" of the previous step has been been organized into a sort of primitive "map" in the internal workings of the compiler, with the numbered tagging struct `BaseViewer` acting as the keys that allow us to view a specific indexed base. (Thus the name.) Like a map, and unlike an array or list, we'll have to handle creating unique keys for our data ourselves. But that's a bit later. For now...
- Third trick: since handling `friend` functions is part of specializing the template, the template instance doesn't necessarily need to be actually constructed to populate its part of the array. Then, we can exploit a certain feature of the C++ specification regarding which possible specializations a compiler must actually generate code for. [Quoth cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Implicit_instantiation),

  > When code refers to a function in context that requires the function definition to exist, or if the existence of the definition affects the semantics of the program (since C++11), and this particular function has not been explicitly instantiated, implicit instantiation occurs. The list of template arguments does not have to be supplied if it can be deduced from context.

  > The existence of a definition of function is considered to affect the semantics of the program if the function is *needed for constant evaluation* by an expression, *even if* constant evaluation of the expression is not required or if constant expression evaluation does not use the definition.

  (emphasis mine). In particular, non-type template parameters are always considered "manifestly constant-evaluated expressions" by the standard, so including a particular specialization of `BaseWriter` into a template parameter is enough to force the compiler to generate code for it (thus producing the friend function, thus populating our "map") even if the template ends up being unused.

  - We add this to a standard application of SFINAE to ensure that the function template we create never gets used and thus never makes it into runtime evaluation. We can now introduce our foundation into a CRTP base that our actual bases can inherit from to trigger the structures we've constructed above:

    ```cpp
    #include <typeindex>
    #include <utility>

    template <typename T>
    struct Base
    {
        template <
            typename D,
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, D>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr,
            typename impl::BaseWriter<D, /*???*/, T>::nonExistent = nullptr
        >
        friend constexpr void registerBases(void *) {}
    };

    //-----------------------

    //Sample object hierarchy for testing
    struct A : Base<A> {};
    struct B : Base<B>, A {};
    struct C : Base<C> {};
    struct D : Base<D>, B, C {};
    ```

    Here, `T` represents one of our base types, which will itself inherit from `Base` in a CRTP way. `D` is the derived class we're querying. Just like with normal `&&` and `||`, template substitution short-circuits if it encounters a substitution failure, so the compiler halts its substitution attempt if D does not derive T. Only if the `enable_if` passes does it try and instantiate the last parameter, which causes the compiler to append `T` into the array we're building. `nullptr` is used as a generic unit type for ignored arguments.
  - Since we've again declared and defined a friend member within our class template, every time we instantiate a class CRTP-derived from `Base` the compiler will automatically add a corresponding `registerBases` function template to the enclosing scope.
  - Of course, as the name implies, `BaseWriter` doesn't actually have a member called `nonExistent` for any values of `T, D`, so substitution will always fail. So there will be no code in the final runtime corresponding directly to `registerBases`.
- Last trick before we tie everything up: ADL lookup. When we call a function by name, ADL has to first build a list of all possible definitions (overloads) of that name. If it encounters a function template by that name, it has to attempt to instantiate that template before it can know whether that definition should be added to the pool of candidates. This means that **just considering** a template is enough to activate all the machinery we have above. All we have to do is add an ADL dummy target somewhere that the compiler can fall back on once it realizes that none of the templates we've given it actually pass substitution. We change the name to `adl_RegisterBases` to document our intent, and put everything we've got together:

```cpp
#include <typeindex>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct tag
{
    using type = T;
};
    
namespace impl {
    // Don't need an ADL dummy for adl_ViewBase since we
    // only ever call it from inside impl::

    template <typename D, std::size_t I>
    struct BaseViewer {
        friend constexpr auto adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer);
    };

    template <typename D, std::size_t I, typename B>
    struct BaseWriter
    {
        friend constexpr auto adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>) {return tag<B>{};}
    };
}

// Do need an ADL dummy for adl_RegisterBases somewhere
// SFINAE disables all the 'active' definitions, and the compiler needs
// to find *something* or it's a hard error, not SFINAE
template <typename T>
constexpr void adl_RegisterBases(void *) {} 

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    template <
        typename D,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, D>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr,
        typename impl::BaseWriter<D, /*???*/, T>::nonExistent = nullptr
    >
    friend constexpr void adl_RegisterBases(void *) {}
};
//-----------------------

//Sample object hierarchy for testing
struct A : Base<A> {};
struct B : Base<B>, A {};
struct C : Base<C> {};
struct D : Base<D>, B, C {};

int main () {
    //ADL hint: by casting to (A *), we tell the compiler to check 
    //scopes related to A for possible overloads of adl_RegisterBases
    //Without the cast, the compiler just immediately instantiates our
    //dummy without actually checking relevant templates.
    //Casting nullptr to (A*) provides the hint without constructing A
    adl_RegisterBases<A>((A *)nullptr);
}
```

Now, all we have to do is figure out that bit we left for last: assigning different numbers to each base in a systematic way we can reproduce at the end. The easiest way to do that is to somehow keep track of the size the "map" for each target (derived class), and assign each new base the latest size of the map as its index.

So, we need something with a base case and general structure that looks like...

```cpp
template<typename D, typename Next, std::size_t I = 0> 
struct NumBases : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};
```

A specific `NumBases` specification can only have a single `::value`, which is a static property that can't be changed over the course of compilation; this is an issue if we intend to use the type template `NumBases` to keep track of the growing length of our map. So, instead we build `NumBases` as representing a particular basetype-index pair `<Next, I>` in itself, and attach it to a particular `BaseViewer` by passing its `::value` to `BaseWriter` in a specialization of `Base`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    template <
        typename D,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, D>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr,
        typename impl::BaseWriter<D, NumBases<D, T>::value, T>::nonExistent = nullptr
    >
    friend constexpr void adl_RegisterBases(void *) {}
};
```

At this point, enough of our code works and compiles that we can start following along with <kbd>[C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/f550fa5f)</kbd>.

Note that `BaseWriter` has generated a specialization `BaseWriter<A,0,A>`, and `NumBases` a specialization `NumBases<A, A, 0>`. Specializing `BaseWriter<A,0,A>` has in turn generated `BaseViewer<A, 0>` and an overload of `viewBase` that accepts `BaseViewer<A, 0>` specifically. We can exploit this with our old friend SFINAE: we can make a specialization of `NumBases` that, being a specialization, will always be checked first, but only passes substitution if a corresponding `BaseViewer` with the right index value `I` (and ignoring `Next`) has already been specialized:

```cpp
struct NumBases<D, Next, I, decltype(adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>{})> : ...
```

If we recursively define `NumBases` in terms of itself, but with `I` replaced with `I+1`, then the recursion will terminate when the specialization stops applying -- that is, when the compiler runs out of existing `BaseViewer`s with appropriate indices. As a side effect, by the same mechanism that populates our "map" in the first place, consideration by ADL will also instantiate `BaseViewer<D, I+1>`, incrementing the counter and preparing the stage for the next call to `NumBases{}`.

For clarity's sake, we move the SFINAE logic into its own template type parameter, so `NumBases` is now defined as

```cpp
template<typename D, typename Next, std::size_t I = 0, typename = void>
struct NumBases : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};

template<typename D, typename Next, std::size_t I>
struct NumBases<D, Next, I, decltype(adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>{}), void())
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, NumBases<D, Next, I+1, void>::value> {};
```

And that's the hard parts done: we can confirm with <kbd>[C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/ac4a4181)</kbd> that `NumBases` does its job, giving us the keys (for the test struct named `D`) `BaseViewer<D, 0>` through `BaseViewer<D, 3>` and `BaseWriter<D, 0, A>` through `BaseWriter<D, 3, D>`. We use `std::index_sequence` and parameter pack expansion to enumerate the entries of our "map", package it in a `type_list`:

```cpp
template <typename ...P>
struct type_list
{
    inline static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(P);
};

namespace impl {
    //...
    template <typename T, typename I>
    struct BaseListLow {};
    
    template <typename T, std::size_t ...I>
    struct BaseListLow<T, std::index_sequence<I...>>
    {
        static constexpr type_list<decltype(adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<T, I>{}))...> helper() {}
        using type = decltype(helper());
    };
```

...clean up our code some (packing up the direct call to `adl_RegisterBases`, with its very specific `<T>((T *)nullptr)` syntax, into its own function; making a helper struct `impl::RegisterBases` that hides some implementation details from the point of call in `Base` proper -- this means we have to move `adl_RegisterBases` itself into `impl` so the call from `RegisterBases` can find it):

```cpp
    template <typename D, typename B>
    struct BaseInserter : BaseWriter<D, NumBases<D, B>::value, B> {};

    template <typename T>
    struct RegisterBases : decltype(adl_RegisterBases<T>((T *)nullptr), tag<void>())
    {};

    template <typename T>
    struct BaseList : BaseListLow<T, 
    std::make_index_sequence<(impl::RegisterBases<T>{}, NumBases<T, 
    void>::value)>> {};
} //namespace impl

template <typename T>
using base_list = typename impl::BaseList<T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    template <
        typename D,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, D>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr,
        typename impl::BaseInserter<D, T>::nonExistent = nullptr
    >
    friend constexpr void adl_RegisterBases(void *) {}
};
```

... and silence a few warnings from GCC about our non-templated friend function (probably warning us about exactly the weird `inline`-defeating behavior we had to deal with in step two).

And then the code runs. To use it, use CRTP to include the boilerplate `adl_RegisterBases` friend template in all the bases you want to detect, and then for whatever type `T`, just get the type of `base_list<T>`.

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwArKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIMEADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQLhkTEs8YnBdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BQbaY9o4CdQ0ExdFxCUm29Y3NuW0Ko30RA2VDgQCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BEcjeWADUJv5uTlPEmKzH2CYaAILbu/uYRycEAJ7JmBFYqte3DzMOwYey8h2Obi8jlohHe/3uAIImBYyQMSNebg%2BX2YbAOABVrgdzl4HAd6sAjgB2Kz3A50g5edJGMmfF7HAAi%2BOONIelPZ3IBiORqKY6IhWMYrBeADpZcp4XdiaSJQB9GFTQXUgH0g4RGGRIn1RzIA5oBhTTCqZLEQ3oEAgdIAL0wKoIRLwztenKdmFQVFl0ogykWAoRfNDD3uOMwCmSTA2upRtCpPJ1AHo0wd2QIwBw3ZFMOgDoYDnd2aEDugfCx3gd%2BDamOhaCqAGp4TAAdwsTCU7pBLw7mG19IzBwEtFrmAAbglTWJk4Q68RUCxdea8Ic8En7YLafSkUnRWy3qzo1nSLb7T7XQcAJKEpVu7tKNud2cmLV7nV0qjEdsMIszQtK0GyhVBiybVt2y7HtMAgZ9MFfQdiBDfxU3pD9%2BTQ3c7h1A8RTFE9sSlc9LwdD0XTdW8LwlM8rH8bBDWIEkn1ggB1P8kRtD90O/Jd/0AgRgOtYswIg5skIQ%2BDYKQhIIXZC97wYxYUwOC4CDWBgySYYAIXom4tXDNCqX5L8TIjYc6XwtFj0xU8SIUlliNxKJLQIC8pjtcjnRvW8vQODQaPs3EOQOKdUA3BUdUfA5SgQhQDhAMiIiRYBiDEFUgPqQQIU8q8KNdRTCR4zCLLM6yjwxWiHKC5yXlc1R3LI68qKi%2BkYri2CFHki8Gqa6jK2qWgJQgRsJOgqSENk4gervf5DPZZYwoi9AIEWVCbjMnUkrykAUswNKMqywwCFyggvJa3qfHi2a%2BqKywuAvcLIoY%2B0pzELwhwYlNSuwhFyuFGyquCl5HOq3F9MspiWIOBDb3NBIuMS2H2M4uSTkczqlG6jGL30t6PswPHioWsrcJHTNswOAsixLMsKyrFgazrEhxJVAAlA68AtYh4qJFdOwQBIhzM0chAAMVvKI7kY/AFCYWJ6AS%2BcySFg5c3jRwZ1zQaaAYQpzQvQwiwINW0BROhZxp7rRczIg6x%2BA4ACoFAF02ImAJ2xxtQhc2Vg4EAaIsEmXMhqdQN0JalmWoYqwi7LqrkGKhrLLRE57acgzngG5rj4ogDPnZUkrw3%2B8mrMByrxRBpPNvL6HSWz3OEj5pKsD2Eaxo5rmeZuk4CQYqA8SLhgvFoWhkgIFCaJ0iEM%2BuNaQzMkusJ5WPK/j8GXjxWrJVxJS6%2BiqeYYQ8IplCVAOx%2Boy14Bw9N5rnfmoKt0AwPqGYtP3OL47CEn92n4loVRKAAI6fX7BCW8AZ/jJ2Xp%2BeuR9RR4BNKnECTkXTqlOicduw1WSjUgpJWC0kXzQXRm4J%2B78FrrWgd9IWE8EhrWvqZBB9JGQe3Qf5HBI06FfGIIvCMOpfq33rnHWyW9a4f2PqSL%2BUxkYyL6JfP%2BHlzr2hYEwAA1i6QBqhgGYDAYwDYEIIBblRPaJuvcup/3mlYPkV0WB93IU9Fa1wCbeEwBtEmNjV6ak5BmaMsZ4wvBMbQHCojgaJwHnXNhzJYiwTVLnfy4jgn2nkVY16IAJRkzCdXCJCpP6wU1LxMkG9bJQzwjXBSZT2oqJAJKRWWiqCujOl5bmKpYlKBVH6FUU4lFZmuMoryo9x6T2IE076oUhkTynqQKpVka7JJAHDBGjQyGOUifaBgAhsCqGboIfykyRlQzaj%2BP8rhTRCSRGgwuXdzF5y6gXFaRcmE%2BIjBmAAtB8z5Xzvk/I%2BThDMQhWCoheKgWI2hqhugQO2dK6wEC1nrMUqYHsAQxVwklBCEIHjjNJn9RUUinxyIKScfSF5cIrwjDFNwhKlAQjcJ4oRKL8VZmpV9NwWFsB4wvFS8luKhT3zEY/BUhdrQpTxHgpevIimPCoABTAVADgqgALJCDcK2bA7NJFeTQFCDEEIFUqmUOzbAeI8QAE0VTizkFEcht4ADyUQVQql1ScdWWxAhuAYLmARGEgQdBpWZXa2q3QQj1Y6y11qhC3gAOKOudVSr17rPVbFxYI31AE8BUBeby%2B4KUDhqIiGtQpkikHIBVD2JQjQIAHHaRg3O8kXHeWPFhTkkgDioSKSKwQYqvgQhrfEjUGMYHYELcZUcEoz5YMxLPE4WKOXaV0sS/p87aVLvJPW5ODELwkCwDaNRtZ3rEDhGGdkHBli0E4IEXgfgOBaFIKgTgdLLDWH5msBM2weCkAIJoU9yx1EgEkAADmlJIMwkgNAADYAOUnA5SAAnBoAD/hHrno4JIK93672cF4AoEAgUv03tPaQOAsAYCIBQCuZIlsyAUAgObSj9BEjAAUMwZICgEAR1IFgKcyDELQVtdiTgH6aDDQSDhiAsQMOxAiA0d4gneBSeYIe21YKIVydIObNgghbUMAnBhrAsQvDADcPOHD3BeBYDUUYcQBHON4AuDUGcpnb2WmqFCTYt79oodvTCWIML3geCwBhqeW45PLCoAYJjSF%2BOMDU/wQQIgxDsCkDIQQigVDqBs7oZDhhjDWGsPoPAsQcOQGWKgSemRTNvM8hyUwT7LBmFvagGcxA/xYGK2tdonRMguAAuMPwj0wizFKOUPQqR0hdCyJ4Foo2CgTf6MNoYj0qg1G6NMPrehlsTZ6I0ebgxEhLbW1N3IB3ei7fmPt5YrtX1JbPRe9DNn70cAOKoAD4G3ngdbcAZAJoIDHwYOolSEBcCEFZu%2BxYvB8NaHWqQP9gQuDSkCJSQIsGkNAga7Brg4HYP6E4Gh0gLAkiBWvY1rDthcOfu/csYjZGXPIDAtRygDQmPKEMB0IQ7GOzXo/XRugSCBAs8iLQdnl9ie8B5wxkATGWNsY4%2BLhIUQpSk7l8QW1UJhec4w7Tu4xAmOk9p3UfA17eBxeEKIcQyWTdpbUBhrL%2BgcsoDy5YArRX4ClfK0JTgVXzo1cdxYBrvAmshw3DGV3KxrsbfOhEAXbOOdc4hxcdggUOzpWSKFnHHBL2kFF5hjg2zXNEBtC9t7H2DhfZ%2B39gHBwICPqsE7g4wOC9HCBFwcHFOCPQ6Fo2IYHWUN44J4EInGHHvYfJ5Dn9MOkjw8R8j1H/h0eY%2Bxyh/w92SccAh5T27HAzAr4D6Tsf0PmvpGcJIIAA%3D%3D%3D)</kbd>

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeindex>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct tag {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename ...P>
struct type_list
{
    inline static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(P);
};

namespace impl {
    // Don't need an ADL dummy for adl_ViewBase since we
    // only ever call it from inside impl::

    template <typename D, std::size_t I> struct BaseViewer {
        friend constexpr auto adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer);
    };

    template <typename D, std::size_t I, typename B> struct BaseWriter {
        friend constexpr auto adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>) { return tag<B>{}; }
    };

    template <typename D, typename Next, std::size_t I = 0, typename = void>
    struct NumBases : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};

    template <typename D, typename Next, std::size_t I>
    struct NumBases<D, Next, I, decltype(adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>{}), void())>
        : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, NumBases<D, Next, I+1, void>::value> {};

    template <typename D, typename B>
    struct BaseInserter : BaseWriter<D, NumBases<D, B>::value, B> {};

    // Do need an ADL dummy for adl_RegisterBases somewhere
    // SFINAE disables all the 'active' definitions, and the compiler needs
    // to find *something* or it's a hard error, not SFINAE
    template <typename T>
    constexpr void adl_RegisterBases(void *) {}

    template <typename T>
    struct RegisterBases : decltype(adl_RegisterBases<T>((T *)nullptr), tag<void>())
    {};

    template <typename T, typename I>
    struct BaseListLow {};

    template <typename T, std::size_t ...I>
    struct BaseListLow<T, std::index_sequence<I...>>
    {
        static constexpr type_list<decltype(adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<T, I>{}))...> helper() {}
        using type = decltype(helper());
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct BaseList : BaseListLow<T, std::make_index_sequence<(impl::RegisterBases<T>{}, NumBases<T, void>::value)>> {};
} //namespace impl

template <typename T>
using base_list = typename impl::BaseList<T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    template <
        typename D,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, D>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr,
        typename impl::BaseInserter<D, T>::nonExistent = nullptr
    >
    friend constexpr void adl_RegisterBases(void *) {}
};
//-----------------------

//Sample object hierarchy for testing
struct A : Base<A> {};
struct B : Base<B>, A {};
struct C : Base<C> {};
struct D : Base<D>, B, C {};

template <typename T>
void printType()
{
    #ifndef _MSC_VER
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    #else
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << '\n';
    #endif
};

int main()
{
    static_assert( base_list<D>::size == 4 );
    printType<base_list<D>>(); // typeList<tag<A>, tag<B>, tag<C>, tag<D>>, order may vary
}
```

Comment: I am getting aa lot of "redefinition of adl_Viewbase" trying to run this on c++17. does this require c++20? Everything but `printType<base_list<D>>()` compiles just fine, but once this line is added it just breaks

Comment: Well, yes. The way template programming works, a template that is never specialized generates no code. So until you add that line, the compiled machine code is essentially empty.

Comment: @Zeks That being said, (godbolt)[https://godbolt.org/z/jevYsjh4o] claims that it compiles correctly with c++17 on the latest stable versions of GCC ('trunk'), clang (16.0.0), and MVSC (v19), including the `static_assert` line that should fail if it doesn't actually work. So it shouldn't require c++20.

Comment: `redefinition of adl_Viewbase`... well, first of all, is that a copy-paste? because C++ is case sensitive; if you forward declared that function as `adl_ViewBase` in `BaseViewer`, but then defined it as `adl_Viewbase` in `BaseWriter`, then the trick we used in step 2 to batch-forward-declare all of the templated `adl_ViewBase(BaseViewer<D, I>)` friend functions created by `BaseWriter` with different `B`s as all the same inline function won't do anything.