# How do I determine if a class indirectly inherits from a base class?

Tags: c++

You can use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) to check if a class inherits from some base class, but how do I know if a class doesn't *directly* inherit from that class (i.e inherits indirectly from that class)?

Comment: Are you saying that if `Derived1` inherits from `Base`, and `Derived2` inherits from `Derived1`, you want something that returns `false` given `Derived1` and `Derived2` but returns `true` given `Base` and `Derived2`?

Comment: @RSahu Yes. And I am open to C++11 solutions if they are possible. The answer in the duplicate is good too.

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of the other question. If anything the opposite. BTW, `is_base_of` does not only detect direct bases, IIRC

Comment: [`std::is_convertible<From, To>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) is not enough I guess?

Comment: [N2965](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html) introduces the `bases` and `direct_bases` metafunctions ([discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18435001/33732)), which would make your goal pretty easy to implement. [Support apparently already exists in GCC.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16262354/33732)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible until [N2965](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html) is implemented.