# Get lowest shared base class type in template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have a function that takes two different templated arguments:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void fun(T t, U u);
```

Types T and U are part of the same inheritance tree. I'd like to get the most specific class that they both inherit from.

```
typedef /*something*/ shared_parent;
```

For example, if type `T` and type `U` are the same type, I want that type. If type `T` inherits from type `U`, I want type `U`. If Type `T` and type `U` both inherit from the same parent, I want that parent.

If types `T` and `U` are not part of the same inheritance tree, I don't care what happens.

Comment: I would've thought that [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) would've worked, but ti was designed for something else

Comment: Since C++ supports multiple inheritance, I don't think it is possible to get "that same parent" from template magic. This post might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262354/2950563

Comment: You're correct that std::common_type is something different, but it actually works for my purposes.

Comment: There's no way to do it in present C++. If reflection gets added to the language eventually then you'll be able to write a custom trait that walks up the inheritance trees manually.

Comment: @brian what's wrong with std::common_type?

Comment: @xaxxon it doesn't do this :)

Comment: @Brian it seems like it does at least in some situations: https://godbolt.org/g/nAXPNJ

Comment: @xaxxon only when one of the types is a direct ancestor of the other

Comment: @Brian  I see.  Thank you.  https://godbolt.org/g/DxpUxS

Comment: GCC can do this if `std::tr2::bases` is employed. But AFAICS there's no standard-conforming approach.