# Check if the class has any base class in C++ in compile time

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, std

I want to check whether the class `X` has **ANY** base class using type utilities in C++.

For example:

```
class X : public Y
{
}
static_assert(std::has_base_class<X>::value, "") // OK
```

but:

```
class X
{
}
static_assert(std::has_base_class<X>::value, "") // Failed
```

Does anything like my imaginary `has_base_class` exist in the standard library? Thanks!

Comment: This seems like XY problem, why do you need that info? BTW, what you want is not currently possible

Comment: You can check for a specific base class, but not if the class has any in general.

Comment: You can check the can-be-converted-to-single-type relationship, if that's close enough.

Comment: @super even then, the base class has to be public.

Comment: @lorro [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/euXbCT) seems to disagree.

Comment: @super : my fault, indeed, overload resolution is before accessibility check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can't do exactly this in standard C++. The closest you get from std library is [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of), but it is for testing a specific base class.

But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262354/2169662) GCC has [`std::tr2::bases`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/api/a00907.html) (and `std::tr2::direct_bases`) that solves your question for a generic "has any base" assertion. These came from the [N2965 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html) and unfortunately was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33664204/2169662) for std C++.

Here's a sample code showing how you can use this GCC extension to assert just what you want:

```
#include <tr2/type_traits>

class B {};

class X : public B {};
static_assert(std::tr2::bases<X>::type::empty(),"X");
// doesn't compile because X bases tuple returned is not empty

class Y {};
static_assert(std::tr2::bases<Y>::type::empty(),"Y");

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```