# Is there no way to have shared_ptr be silently created?

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>

class A {};
class B : public A {};

void func( std::shared_ptr<A> ptr )
{
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    func( std::shared_ptr<A>( new B ) );
}
```

The syntax `std::shared_ptr<A>( new B )` requires `A` class to be specified. It's a pain if the class is in a namespace and it makes code too verbose when it actually does not need to.

Is there no STL template function that would make the syntax lighter and have `A` be deduced automatically?
I was thinking of something like: `func( std::make_shared( new B ) )` but that's not what `std::make_shared` is meant for.

I mean, there's the same for `pair`, you can use `std::make_pair` without having to specify what are the first/second pair types, ther are automatically deduced. Is there not "equivalent" for `shared_ptr`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262338/get-base-class-for-a-type-in-class-hierarchy. Afaik you cannot find the base class given a derived type.

Comment: even if you could, what would you expect for `struct X {}; struct Y {}; struct A : X {}; struct B : A,Y {};` ? which base is the most basy base of `B` ?

Comment: `but that's not what std::make_shared is meant for.` Why do you think so? As far as I can tell, this is an ideal use case for it. Unlike your example, that one doesn't have undefined behaviuor.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: If func takes `shared_ptr<A>` it would pickup `A`. If it takes `shared_ptr<Y>` it would pickup `Y`. If it's overloaded and takes both, I would expect an error saying the compiler is unable to deduce the argument...

Comment: @eerorika: What would be the syntax then? I could not use `std::make_shared` without specifying `A` template parameter.

Comment: @jpo38 You don't specify A since you're not creating an A object. You specify B because you are creating a B object.

Comment: `std::make_shared<B>()`? https://godbolt.org/z/nhc6WK

Comment: @eerorika: I mean the syntax will be `std::make_shared<A>( ... )`, while I'm looking for `std::some_function( new B )`, as I d'ont want `A` class to be specified, I want it to be automatically deduced.

Comment: @jpo38 That would be a wrong syntax for creating a `B` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but that's not what std::make_shared is meant for.

On the contrary, this is an ideal use case for `std::make_shared`:

```
 func(std::make_shared<B>());
```

Not only was no need to specify `A`, but also we have the advantage of the pointed object and the control block having a shared allocation.

---

Your example has undefined behaviour because the shared pointer would delete the object through pointer to a non-polymorphic base. This `make_shared` version doesn't have that problem.

Comment: All right, That's just what I was looking for and I was surprised `std::make_shared` did not help...but I was simply not using `make_shared`correctly!